# Error 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: javascript, wavesplatform

I am using the NODE API on the Test network (https://nodes-testnet.wavesnodes.com) and when I make multiple requests from an invoke script I am getting the following error:
**503 Service Temporarily Unavailable**

This error does not always appear, even decreasing the number of requests the error still appears in constant cases.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
    for (let i = 1; i < bets.length; i++) {
      const paramsProv = {
        fee: 500000,
        dApp: config.roulette.contract,
        call: {
          function: 'playRoulette',
          args: [
            { type: 'integer', value: bets[i] },
            { type: 'string', value: signedScript.id }
          ]
        },
        payment: [{ assetId: config.asset.wbet, amount: amounts[i] * 100000000 }],
        version: 1,
        chainId: config.waves.chain
      }
      const signedRoletteScript = invokeScript(paramsProv, seed);
      roulettePlays.push(broadcast(signedRoletteScript, config.waves.node));
    }

    await Promise.all(roulettePlays);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are limits for requests per second for public nodes (https://nodes-testnet.wavesnodes.com). You can find exact numbers here - https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/waves-node/api-limitations-of-the-pool-of-public-nodes

For your endpoint, it is 100 per second from one IP address.